# How to edit code to remove pylint error "unused sympy imported as sp"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I have some code that currently returns the pylint error:

source.py:2:0: W0611: Unused sympy imported as sp (unused-import)

there is a clue: "Note: parse_expr() is available for you to use in this function and sympy has been imported into this question as sp" but I don't understand what to do.

It works fine in my WingIDE but is failing on the server I submit it. Any input on how to change the code to not have this error would be appreciated. Code is below :)

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy import Eq, solve
def num_intersections(expressions):
    """return a list of the number of times each expression 
in this list intersects with every other expression."""
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(expressions)):
        expressions[i] = parse_expr(expressions[i])
    new_exp_lst = expressions
    for expp in expressions:
        intersection_cnt = 0
        new_exp_lst.remove(expp)
        for n_expp in new_exp_lst:
            intersection_cnt += len(solve(Eq(expp, n_expp), list=True))
        lst.append(intersection_cnt)
        new_exp_lst.append(expp)
    return lst
```

Comment: the module comment should be before any import statements.

Comment: that's not it, still get the same errors and now 2 more about how the import is supposed to be at the top.

Comment: Will you mark which line causes each error?

Comment: A doc string for a function should be inside the function, not before it.

Comment: that has fixed the string error, how do i get rid of the unused sympy error?

Comment: also would this help: Note: As with the questions above, parse_expr() is available for you to use in this function and sympy has been imported into this question as sp.

Answer (score 0):

It look like your professor already imported sympy for you as sp and is doing some magic to append your code to its own file that he/she then lint with pylint. Use `sp.x` when you need sympy, i.e.

Instead of

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy import Eq, solve
```

Use:

```
import sympy as sp # Remove that before submitting
```

And then replace `len(solve(Eq(expp, n_expp), list=True))` by `len(sp.solve(sp.Eq(expp, n_expp), list=True))` (among others).